# Combining multiple 2D DataFrames index-wise in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have three different DataFrames (with the matching number of columns and rows, 3x3 in this sample):

```
DataFrame1   DataFrame2   Dataframe3

A1 A2 A3     B1 B2 B3     C1 C2 C3 
A4 A5 A6     B4 B5 B6     C4 C5 C6
A7 A8 A9     B7 B8 B9     C7 C8 C9
```

I want to *combine* them into new DataFrame. Values from each *source* dataframe should be put into separate column. So the expected result would look like this:

```
ResultDataFrame

A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
...
A9 B9 C9
```

How could I achieve that? I looked through samples in Pandas documentation [about merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#) but wasn't able to find case that would match my needs.

My only idea right now is to somehow *flatten* source DFs into Series, and then prepare new DF -> but I'm quite sure it is not the most clever and efficient way.

Comment: As you need to flatten and concatenate, you strategy can not be very much improved anyway. What have you try so far ?

Comment: Well, I was just wondering if there is some clever way to achieve the resulting DataFrame. Right now I went for flattening DFs using df.to_numpy().flatten(). Then, I create final dataframe by using flattened source DFs in constructor. I am wonderinig though if this is optimal solution (but maybe I am too sensitive :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)).astype(str)
dfs = {x: x+df for x in 'ABC'}
```

```
{'A':     0   1   2
      0  A1  A2  A3
      1  A4  A5  A6
      2  A7  A8  A9,
 'B':     0   1   2
      0  B1  B2  B3
      1  B4  B5  B6
      2  B7  B8  B9,
 'C':     0   1   2
      0  C1  C2  C3
      1  C4  C5  C6
      2  C7  C8  C9}
```

You can use `pandas.concat` and `stack`:

```
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).stack(1)
```

Or if the input is a list `l` of the dataframes:

```
pd.concat(dict(enumerate(l)), axis=1).stack(1)

# or

pd.concat(l, keys=['A', 'B', 'C'], axis=1).stack(1))
```

output:

```
      A   B   C
0 0  A1  B1  C1
  1  A2  B2  C2
  2  A3  B3  C3
1 0  A4  B4  C4
  1  A5  B5  C5
  2  A6  B6  C6
2 0  A7  B7  C7
  1  A8  B8  C8
  2  A9  B9  C9
```